# What instance of the Object is this method returning?

Tags: java, reflection, instanceof

I have written a below method but I need to find the instance of `object` returned.Also I need to check if it is a `JSON` type or other type returned then will this method work?

```
public class DynamicObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DynamicObject obj = new DynamicObject();

        if(obj.testObj() instanceof String)
            System.out.println("String");
        else if (obj.testObj() instanceof Array)
            System.out.println("Integer Array");
        else if (obj.testObj() instanceof Integer)
            System.out.println("Integer");


    }

    private Object testObj(){
        boolean test = false;
        String s= new String("test");
        Integer in[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
        if(test){
            return s;
        }else{
            return in;
        }
    }

}
```

What shall be the instance of this case.If I run this then console doesn't show anything.

Comment: what do you mean by "JSON type"? Is it an Object or a String?

Comment: Ok is this method sufficient even if I return a JSON object?Since everything falls under Object class I presume it may work.But am I right?

Comment: If you want to detect a JSON OBJECT, then you can use instanceof JSON. If you want to know if your JSON OBJECT contains an array, an integer or a string, it's a completely different story and, of course, this code won't work.

Comment: As an aside, you are using 'instance' wrongly here. String is not an 'instance' of object but a 'subclass'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instanceof should be Integer[]

```
else if (obj.testObj() instanceof Integer[])
            System.out.println("Integer Array");
```

Comment: HI, great answer.But will this even work for JSON and other format?

Comment: @Nilesh I don't understand your question. But you can find more information here: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/0400__instanceof.htm

Answer (score 2):

Java arrays are not subclasses of java.lang.reflect.Array.

In other words, the integer array FAILS the test

```
(obj.testObj() instanceof Array)
```

Answer (score 1):

`testObj()` will return an array of Integers, whose type in Java is written as `Integer[]`. In `main()`, you only test for instances of `String`, `Array`, and `Integer`, so no print statement is ever reached.

If you were to change the second test from `Array` to `Integer[]`, it would work as you intended:

```
else if (obj.testObj() instanceof Integer[])
    System.out.println("Integer Array");
```

The reason using `obj.testObj() instanceof Array` doesn't work is because the `java.lang.reflect.Array` class is not actually a superclass of Java arrays. As per the [JavaDoc page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html), the class "provides static methods to dynamically create and access Java arrays" - it is not an array itself, it is just a utility to create and access arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Get type of the object:

```
Class cls = obj.testObj().getClass(); 
System.out.println("The type of the object is: " + cls.getName());
```